# Limit column length to character length instead of byte length

Tags: mariadb

I use the utf8mb4 database character set and collate databases as utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci; I'm very aware that some characters may take up to *4 bytes* per character.

In MariaDB is there a way to limit a value based on characters instead of bytes?

In example if I want to require a maximum and minimum number of characters (for something like a meta description for a page) I'm only interested in the character length and I'm well aware that if every single character uses 4 bytes that I should have the column support up to four times the maximum byte limit and have column types may (or may not) come in to play. I obviously can handle this in the programming language though I'd like to better familiarize myself with these aspects of databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

*is* limited to 100 *characters*, not bytes.  That example will take *up to* 400 bytes, plus a 2-byte length field.

To limit the *minimum* would require a `CHECK` clause.